# Plotly dash user dependent server side caching

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm using server side caching in my `dash` application and I've followed example 4 in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks). I'm using this to query and process the "global" data, this prepared dataset is then shared between different components in the application.

I'm trying to tweak the example such that the caching also depends and reloads on some user input.

I've tried with something like below which doesn't really make sense - what is the best approach to achieve what I'm after?

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

cache = Cache(app.server, config={
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis',
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem',
    'CACHE_DIR': 'cache-directory',
    'CACHE_THRESHOLD': 200
})

def get_dataframe(session_id, user_input_value):
    @cache.memoize()
    def query_and_serialize_data(session_id):
        df = # Here I make my query based on user_input_value 
             # If there is no input I just return an empty df
        return df.to_json()
    return pd.read_json(query_and_serialize_data(session_id))

def serve_layout():
    session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    return html.Div([
        html.Div(session_id, id='session-id', style={'display': 'none'}),
        # User input            
        # My output which doesn't behave as expected
    ])

app.layout = serve_layout

# Callback related to the user input

@app.callback(
    [
        Output('my-output', 'output-component')
    ],
    [
        Input('session-id', 'children'),
        Input('user-input', 'value')
    ]
)
def generate_output(session_id, user_input_value):
    df = get_dataframe(session_id, user_input_value)
    return # Output component

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have posted, the `user_input_value` value never reaches the memoized function. If you change your code so that it does, i.e. pass the `user_input_value` to the `query_and_serialize_data` function, it should work as intended

```
def get_dataframe(session_id, user_input_value):
    @cache.memoize()
    def query_and_serialize_data(session_id, user_input_value):
        df = # Here I make my query based on user_input_value 
             # If there is no input I just return an empty df
        return df.to_json()
    return pd.read_json(query_and_serialize_data(session_id, user_input_value))
```

Comment: Thanks! That should do it. Althogh I've now also learned that `dash-extensions` `ServersideOutput` might be a cleaner solution. My approach above would require the user input to be passed on to every callback using the "global" data.